# Trying to use while loop with multiple conditions in python

Tags: python, while-loop

```
guests0, guests1 = ['Jane','Katy', 'Michelle'], ['John','Keth','Mike']

while guests0 != [] and guests1 != []:
    doorkeeper = print('Who is there?')
    name = input().capitalize()
    if name in guests0:
        guests0.remove(name)
        print('Welcome, ', name)
    elif name in guests1:
        guests1.remove(name)
        print('Welcome, ', name)
    else:
        print('Sorry, we are closed')
    print(guests0)
    print(guests1)
```

I wanted the loop keep going until there's no more names in both list. But the loop continues until only one condition is met. I don't know what exactly is wrong and how can I fix this. And also I wanted to use only very simple, basic mrthods to solve this problem.

Comment: Sounds like your `and` should be an `or`.

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned, you should use an `or` not `and`

Why?
Evaluate using a truth table:

| `guests0 != []` | `guests1 != []` | and | or |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | True | True |
| True | False | False | True |

In the first row you can see that when we start both are not empty.
Then in the second row, when we've emptied a list the comparison results in a `False` when using `and` because one list is empty.